# Class() returns multiple multiple class names in R

Tags: r, class, object

All,
I am a beginner in R. I am not too familiar with how classes are organized in R. I have noticed that some class() calls return one class-type, while others return multiple class names.

**Example 1**

{My object name is "sassign"}
Here's my data:

```
 acctnum gender state   zip zip3 first last book_ nonbook_ total_ purch child youth cook do_it refernce art geog buyer
1   10001      M    NY 10605  106    49   29   109      248    357    10     3     2    2     0        1   0    2    no
2   10002      M    NY 10960  109    39   27    35      103    138     3     0     1    0     1        0   0    1    no
3   10003      F    PA 19146  191    19   15    25      147    172     2     0     0    2     0        0   0    0    no
4   10004      F    NJ 07016  070     7    7    15      257    272     1     0     0    0     0        1   0    0    no
5   10005      F    NY 10804  108    15   15    15      134    149     1     0     0    1     0        0   0    0    no
6   10006      F    NY 11366  113     7    7    15       98    113     1     0     1    0     0        0   0    0   yes
```

Now, if I do class(object) above, I get:

```
class(sassign)
[1] "data.frame"
```

I am good with this. I understand that this data structure is of type data frame.

**Example 2**
Now, I recently came across Wickham's tibbleR package. 
Here's how I converted data frame to Tibble:

```
tib_sassign<-as_data_frame(sassign)
class(tib_sassign)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

This is where I was lost. I do not know the differences between tbl_df and tbl. However, my hypothesis is that Tibble package makes our life easier by returning objects (similar to abstract classes) that can be used as a tibble ("tbl"), data frame ("data.frame") or tbl_df (*I have no clue what tbl_df means*). I read through dplyr package's online pdf, but I don't think they have explained this. I believe they assume that people know what above would mean.

I read RStudio's blog on https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/24/tibble-1-0-0/ but I dont think they have described what the above output means. I also read Norman Matloff's book, but I don't think this is covered. 
I also googled "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame", but most of the results were pertaining to some piece of code not working. I couldn't find an explanation of what above output means.

**Example 3**
I have now started to look at Time Series in R. This is where I got to a point that I have to start this thread. 
Here's what I did:

```
t_sassign <-data.frame(group_by(sassign,last))
t_sassign<-ts(t_sassign,start = c(2014,1),frequency = 12)
class(t_sassign)
[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
```

Here, "last" is the # of months.  While I do believe I will somehow manage what I need to do, but I still don't get what the above result means.

I also searched through StackOverflow, but most of the results talk about returning Class in JAVA.

I have three questions:

**Question 1)** It will be awesome if someone could provide an example so that I can understand the output from class()

**Question 2)** I'd also appreciate if someone could provide a snippet with an application of concept discussed in question 1. This way, I can register this concept in my brain forever.

**Question 3)** If you know a book that goes into such concepts, I'd appreciate it. I am following R in Action by Kabackoff, R by Norman Matloff and StackOverflow.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

---

(Added)
Here's another confusing thing: 
When I did:

```
AP<-AirPassengers
class(AP)
[1] "ts"
```

I got "ts" as class type. Inherited classes were not shown. I am really lost. Please help me!

Comment: I think this is simply off topic here because this is a broad question about a fundamental concept of R; however, you can read up on what `class` returns here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html

Comment: Not a bad question though. Incomprehensible downvote.

Comment: Thank you so much, Konrad. I did go through the link you have posted. However, I believe Wickham focuses more on threads and Nesting. I am not quite sure whether he talks about the three classes in class() function. Please correct me if I am wrong. I have gone through tonnes of material on the web, but I couldn't find any resource. If you can explain it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You must have looked at the wrong link! — The link I posted doesn’t mention threading and nesting (?) at all. It does talk about the `class` function and explains what it means.

Comment: The idea behind the `class` function in R is to offer an object-oriented style of programming. Calling the `class` function on an R object returns all the classes that object is made of (i.e. its immediate class along with all the classes that immediate class `inherits` from). For instance, when you coerce a normal `data.frame` (a native R object) into a `tbl_df`, you are changing its immediate class from `data.frame` to `tbl_df`.
You can check if an R object inherits from a class by using the `inherits` function.

Comment: For example: `inherits(as_data_frame(sassign), what = 'data.frame')` should return `TRUE`, just like `inherits(ts(sassign), what = 'matrix')` should return `TRUE` too.

Comment: Thanks Abdou. So, if I understand you correctly, here's how the inheritance is done: "tbl_df" -> "tbl"  -> "data.frame"? I searched for the inheritance diagram but I couldn't find it. So, I thought of asking you about it.

Comment: In that case, yes. `data.frame` is a native R object, on top of which `tbl` and `tbl_df` are built. I did not design the `dplyr` package, but I am going to go out on a limb and say that the idea behind it was to provide an object that has the basic properties of a `data.frame` with additional enhancements. Both `tbl_df` and `data.table` inherit from `data.frame`. `time-series` objects inherit from `matrix` object.

Comment: Consider [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). For example, when you dump an object to the console, R first looks for `print.class` where `.class` is the appropriate class. In your 2nd example, it finds `print.tbl_df` and prints something less screen-hogging. However, there may be other polymorphic functions that don't know about `tbl_df`, so R then looks for (say) `print.tbl` and `print.data.frame`, using the first it finds. If nothing is found, it uses `print.default`. By having multiple classes, all will be searched for appropriate methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't something from base R but rather a feature of what is often referred to as the 'hadleyverse'. Hadley has designed the `dplyr` package to work with a special version of dataframes. See: http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.1/topics/tibble-package for a description of the tbl_df class. That class has versions of `print`, "[", and "[[" that differ from those functions from base-R that would normally handle dataframes as described there. Different printing format and rules, `$` and `[[` never do partial name matching, and subsetting always returns a data.frame.

Re: a separate description for the tbl-class. What I have found so far suggests to me that `dplyr`-package docs are the place to look, since it has `as.tbl` and descriptions of difference methods for different kinds of data-sources such as SQL servers.

A correction. That package is NOT named `tibbleR`

For you last question (noting that multipart questions are frowned on in SO) You can see that `?inherits` will sometimes but not always tell you if an objects= is a member of an "implicit" class and that you may need to use an `is-` function to test for 'numeric':

```
> AP<-AirPassengers
> class(AP)
[1] "ts"
> inherits(AP, "matrix")
[1] FALSE
> inherits(AP, "numeric")
[1] FALSE
> str(AP)
 Time-Series [1:144] from 1949 to 1961: 112 118 132 129 121 135 148 148 136 119 ...
> inherits( as.matrix(AP), "numeric")
[1] FALSE
> inherits( as.matrix(AP), "matrix")
[1] TRUE
> str( as.matrix(AP) )
 num [1:144, 1] 112 118 132 129 121 135 148 148 136 119 ...
> inherits( as.matrix(AP), "integer")
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric( as.matrix(AP) )
[1] TRUE
> ?inherits
```